# Java - Filter only matched object from list of objects in Mongodb Document

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, kotlin

How to filter only matched object in list of objects in mongodb Java

```
> db.reports.find({'productViews.productId' : {$lte: "1234"}},{"productViews" : 1})
```

returns

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c062a2dfcd262039c7cb592"),
"productViews" : 
   [ 
    { "productId" : "1234", "views" : "2" },
    { "productId" : "3214", "views" : "34" }
   ] 
}
```

The above query return all the values of the array, but I want only the object which matches the provided object. Please advice how to do this in java

```
fun getProductViews(mongoDatabase: MongoDatabase) {
    val report = mongoDatabase.getCollection("reports")
    val result = report.find(Filters.lte("productViews.productId", "20"))
    print(result)
}


@Document(collection = "reports")
data class Report(

    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)
    var reportId: String = Date().toString(),
    var productViews: ArrayList<ProductViews>,
    var categoryViews: ArrayList<CategoryViews>,
  )
```

Comment: Please update your question with spring-boot MongoRepository & spring-boot model for this query? You can easily do it via spring-boot.I hope you tagged spring-boot so we can use spring-boot

Comment: @VelNaga I have updated the question

Comment: Where is your repository class? Could you please also paste you Report Bean?